# virtualbox putty to host(mac) from guest (windows 7) machine

Tags: macos, virtualbox, windows-7-x64, putty

I have windows 7 as a guest virtual box VM on my host (Mac). I'm trying to connect to my host machine (Mac) from the guest VM (windows 7) via putty. Can some please help with this setup.

`Host - Mac V 10.11`

`VM Guest - Windows 7`

`VirtualBox V 4.3.30`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the silly question. Solved it by enabling the remote login on Host (Mac) Here is the link for others just in case [bluishcoder.co.nz/articles/mac-ssh.html](http://bluishcoder.co.nz/articles/mac-ssh.html)